# Is possible to update Samsung fw in region where isn't official supported

Tags: android, galaxy

I own Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 NT-8000 and live in country where OTA updates are not available  yet. Probably they will never be ;-) So I want to update FW manually through ODIN. I've read many how to manuals but still not sure if I upgrade new SAMSUNG FW in region where It is not still available will be still able to make calls and use data services. I will be upgrading last original FW by Samsung 4.1.1. Thx for any suggestions.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start this off by saying that this is not the right place for chatting about this sort of thing, however will give a quick answer as this seems like a first time offence.

I would suggest having a look over at [XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/) for resources. Been there since the WinMo 6 days and has always been top dog for mobile hacking.

As far as I know from my days of plentiful I-9000 flashing, ROM's (the Android Bit) are largely independent from the Modem (The Phone Bit) and the Kernel (The low level hardware interface stuff). I would feel safe if I were you flashing an international rooted stock ROM for the *EXACT* model number as yours. Just be sure to back up all your apps with something like TiBackup.